# ASP.NET MVC: How to setup web.config for LDAP authentication?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, configuration, active-directory, ldap

I have a working LDAP Server with these parameters:

```
OU=users,OU=mydomain,O=this domain
LDAP://myhost:389
```

I **successfully** access **with a generic ldap client**, like the good Jarek Gawor's ldap browser/client with following settings:

```
OU=users,OU=mydomain,O=this domain
User info (append base DN):
uid=myid
password=mypwd
```

I tried to to the same with ASP.NET, getting always the error "**wrong username or password**".
May you help me to setup web.config with above parameters, please?
I did many tries, like changing connectionUsername, removing domainname, putting uid=myid, etc...

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://myhost:389"/>
  ....

<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
         connectionProtection="None"
         connectionUsername="MYDOMAIN\myid"
         connectionPassword="mypwd"
         attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
         enableSearchMethods="True" />
  </providers>
</membership>
......
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `mypass` or `mypwd` or it's just a typo?

Comment: Sorry @WiktorZychla, it was just an example. I standardized password as mypwd. THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded in getting it work with the following *web.config* setup.

There were two problems/errors:

1st) I did not specify the container, so I followed @Kevin's hints:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://myhost:389/O=this domain,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com"/>
  ....
```

I think that was relevant the CN, while **O** could be omitted here, but I do not think this is very important...

2nd) I put the DN base and username (in the form uid=) together inside **connectionUsername** parameter:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
<add name="DefaultMembershipProvider"
     type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
     connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
     connectionProtection="None"
     connectionUsername="uid=myid, O=this domain"
     connectionPassword="mypwd"
     attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
     enableSearchMethods="True" />
```

Please note, in my case I needed to put uid=myid. I do not know if this could be a general solution; perhaps it is related to ADAS configuration of my company, I do not know. I hope this can help some of you...please vote up if you find this solution useful, thx.

@Kevin: Thank you very much. You have been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The only item missing seems to be the default ou. Have you tried adding the trailing entry below "**/CN=Users,DC=testdomain1,DC=test,DC=com**" ?

```
add name="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://testdomain1.test.com/CN=Users,DC=testdomain1,DC=test,DC=com"
```

I got the above from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx

Comment: Thank you @Kevin. Unfortunately it does not work. 
Anyway with other ldap clients I just set DN base = "OU=users,OU=mydomain,O=this domain" and append uid=myid & password=mypwd to base DN...
I did several attempts, changing username with myid@mydomain, mydomain\myid, myd, uid=myid, etc....

Comment: I am assuming the username/password does not have any strange characters which could cause this issue. Not sure how much control you have over the envrionment, but sniffing the network packets and/or accessing the AD logs would also be useful. You have apparently tried everything else !

Comment: THX Kevin! I succeed to get it work! Just now I cannot put here as solution, due my account limit (I have less than 100 rep). I'll put full answer into the next 8 hours, thx
There were two problems/errors.

1st) I did not specify the container, so I followed Kevin hints:
2nd) I put the DN base and username together inside connectionUsername parameter:
...
         connectionUsername="uid=myid, O=this domain"

I do not know if this could be a general solution,pheraps is related to ADAS configuration of my company, I do not know.

@Kevin: Thank you very much. I you have been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

WebConfig

```
<add key="LDAPPath" value="LDAP://ip/DC=company,DC=com" />
<add key="LDAPDomain" value="ta" />
```

C# code

LoginRslt = adAuth.IsAuthenticated(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["LDAPDomain"].ToString(), _username, _password);